# How to use $match in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So currently I am struggling to get the right results from my query.
Here is how it looks:

```
db.pitching.aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$playerid",
        maxIpouts: { $max: "$ipouts" }
    }}
])
```

I know that I have to use **`$match`** to get the right results. I want to get a single player has the highest (**`$max`**) ipouts, but im not sure how to filter that using **`$match`**.

Without **`$match`** it gives me the **`player_id`** and each ipout for the player rather than a single player id having the highest `ipout`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline for this, you just need to append the following pipeline steps to your current query (minus the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**) to get the result you want.

**[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** - As you get the results from the previous **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline, you would need to order the documents by the `maxIpouts` field so that you get the documents with the most `ipouts` ordered.

**[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)** - This will give you the top document.

Now, assembling the above together you should run the following pipeline to get the desired result:

```
db.pitching.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$playerid",
            "maxIpouts": { "$max": "ipouts" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "maxIpouts": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 1 } 
])
```